# How to get missing Source Image name in Unity3d?

Tags: image, unity-game-engine

Is there way to get the missing image name directly?

[Missing Sprite](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwxua.png)

Comment: Can you elaborate? It's not totally clear what you are asking. Are you trying to retrieve "None (Sprite)" as a string?

Comment: Oops, Invalid picture, edited 1 post.

Comment: I try to receive the correct names for the missing images.
For example, i have image with the name table1.png in Resources folder, but it isn't correct name. Correct name of the source image for object is: table_01.png but how I can get the correct name, if Unity give only to me: Missing (Sprite). Yes, sprite is missing but what the "true/correct" name of the missing sprite??? How to find, to get?

Answer (score 0):

Go to image inside your project files, click on it and in Inspector you will see Texture type property. Check if it is set to `Sprite (2D and UI)` since by default when you add image it is set to `default` and some unity components can't see it.